# Evaluate this integral by changing it into polar coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the integral by changing to polar coordinates

$$\int ^1 _{x=0} \int ^x _{y=0} \tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})\,dy\,dx$$

What would the limits for the polar coordinates be?

Comment: Are you sure about the limits of integration! It doesn't make sense! :) I mean what is that $x$ there? The first limits cannot be dependent!

Comment: Yes, the limits are $0\lt x \lt1 $ and $0\lt y \lt x$

Comment: So you have written it in a wrong way! :)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't believe I have! I double checked it and that is how it's written! Could you explain further please. Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at the edit of the question. :)

Comment: Hint: in polar coordinates we have $\theta = \tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x}$.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you for that! I have made an attempt at the question, would this be correct $0 \lt \theta \lt  \frac {\pi}{4}$  $0 \lt r \lt \frac{1}{\cos(\theta)}$

Comment: @JONATHONDOEING Yes, that is correct!

Comment: @MathMajor Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following

$$\eqalign{
  & \theta  = \arctan {y \over x}  \cr 
  & dxdy = rdrd\theta  \cr} $$

and your integral will be

$$\int_{x = 0}^1 {\int_{y = 0}^x {{{\tan }^{ - 1}}} } ({y \over x}){\mkern 1mu} dy{\mkern 1mu} dx = \int_{\theta  = 0}^{{\pi  \over 4}} {\int_{r = 0}^{{1 \over {\cos \theta }}} {r\theta } } {\mkern 1mu} dr{\mkern 1mu} d\theta $$

Comment: Thank you very much! Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: @JONATHONDOEING: Welcome to MSE and enjoy the community. :) You can select answers by check-marking them. Notice the check mark next to each answer. :)